# Problem writing custom AN Sockets

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I have written a custom AN socket that passes instances of a custom class between custom nodes. The socket works when connecting two nodes (1 output to 1 input). However when connecting an output to two inputs, only one of the input nodes is activated and the second is ignored.

My socket code follow. Any suggestions?

Thanks, Mike

```
class ChannelMessageSocket(bpy.types.NodeSocket, AnimationNodeSocket):
bl_idname = "an_ChannelMessageSocket"
bl_label = "VN ChannelMessage Socket"
dataType = "BaseChannelMessage"
allowedInputTypes = ["BaseChannelMessage"]
drawColor = (0.32, 0.32, 0.18, 1)
storable = False
comparable = False

value = None

def getValue(self):
    return self.value

def setProperty(self, data):
    self.value = data

def getProperty(self):
    return self.value
```

Appending Requested Materials:
This is the screen shot. The 1-2 relationship is between the instrument to Control Change / Note-Object Mapper nodes. 
[image]

Code:

```
import bpy, mathutils, sys
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Quaternion, Euler
from time import perf_counter as getCurrentTime
animation_nodes = sys.modules.get('animation_nodes-master')
random_number_cache = animation_nodes.algorithms.random.getRandomNumberCache()
_node_execution_times = animation_nodes.execution.measurements.getMeasurementsDict()
nodes = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeTree'].nodes

# retrieve nodes
_82vvj6ef83nt43p = nodes['VN Instrument Three.001']
_czn2u5yds18qy65 = nodes['Note Object Mapper.001']
_w96de9hsfi7vkpd = nodes['Logic Operators']
_gelmvdkn0lh08oy = nodes['Object Attribute Input']
_kmfum7gowyg3hy5 = nodes['Convert']
_uzyd2z9777am3qs = nodes['Combine Vector']
_xxo7ksek4tpgj17 = nodes['Vector Math']
_t7x899vo7iw5ed1 = nodes['Object Transforms Output']
_yu5oo5wqbz73ttf = nodes['Object Visibility Output']
_9540zjn74dmanlk = nodes['Keyframes']
_8xw1ztvfxj8r5si = nodes['Control Change.001']

# get values
_textBlock_czn = _czn2u5yds18qy65.inputs[1].getValue()
_x_uzy = _uzyd2z9777am3qs.inputs[0].getValue()
_z_uzy = _uzyd2z9777am3qs.inputs[2].getValue()
_b_xxo = _xxo7ksek4tpgj17.inputs[1].getValue()
_location_t7x = _t7x899vo7iw5ed1.inputs[1].getValue()
_rotation_t7x = _t7x899vo7iw5ed1.inputs[2].getValue()
_hideSelect_yu5 = _yu5oo5wqbz73ttf.inputs[3].getValue()
_showName_yu5 = _yu5oo5wqbz73ttf.inputs[4].getValue()
_showAxis_yu5 = _yu5oo5wqbz73ttf.inputs[5].getValue()
_showXRay_yu5 = _yu5oo5wqbz73ttf.inputs[6].getValue()
_controllerNum_8xw = _8xw1ztvfxj8r5si.inputs[0].getValue()



# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'VN Instrument Three.001'
_channelNum_82v, _channelRec_82v, _channelMute_82v, _channel_82v = _82vvj6ef83nt43p.execute()

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Note Object Mapper.001'
_objectOut_czn, _channel_82v, _noteNum_czn, _frameNumber_czn, _enabled_czn, _enabledNot_czn, _velocity_czn, _instObjects_czn = _czn2u5yds18qy65.execute(_channel_82v, _textBlock_czn)

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Logic Operators'
_result_w96 = _enabled_czn or _enabledNot_czn

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Object Attribute Input'
try:
    _gelmvdkn0lh08oy.errorMessage = ''
    _value_gel = _objectOut_czn['velocity']
except:
    if _objectOut_czn: _gelmvdkn0lh08oy.errorMessage = 'Attribute not found'
    _value_gel = None

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Convert'
try: _new_kmf = float(_value_gel)
except: _new_kmf = 0

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Combine Vector'
_vector_uzy = Vector((_x_uzy, _new_kmf, _z_uzy))

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Vector Math'
_result_xxo = mathutils.Vector((_vector_uzy[0] * _b_xxo[0], _vector_uzy[1] * _b_xxo[1], _vector_uzy[2] * _b_xxo[2]))

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Object Transforms Output'
if _objectOut_czn is not None:
    _objectOut_czn.scale = _result_xxo

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Object Visibility Output'
if _objectOut_czn is not None:
    _objectOut_czn.hide = _enabledNot_czn
    _objectOut_czn.hide_render = _enabledNot_czn
    pass

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Keyframes'
_9540zjn74dmanlk.execute(_result_w96, _channelRec_82v, _objectOut_czn, _instObjects_czn)

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Control Change.001'
_controllerValue_8xw = _8xw1ztvfxj8r5si.execute(_controllerNum_8xw, _channel_82v)
```

Comment: hmm can you share a Screenshot of the node setup? and maybe take a look at the generated execution code (you can print it in the developer Panel)

Comment: also what exactly do you mean with "activated" and "ignored"?

Comment: I placed print()'s in the socket's get / set property & value methods so can see them activated, which they are not when the output is connected to two inputs. Can you provide an email to make it easier to send the screenshot and code? Mine is mikechristiansen2000@gmail.com so you do not need to expose on this board.

Comment: Ahh I see. The get/set property functions are only to copy the value from one socket to another. Only the getValue method is called when you have an unlinked input socket of that type. (somehow your mail adress does not work.. it gives me an error, not sure why. However we will be able to fix this here on stackexchange!) For my mail adress look on github.

Comment: Jacques, Please hold off on any further analysis. I see that both nodes are activated but that nothing is being passed to the ControlChange across the socket.

Comment: I am closing this question. The source of the problem had nothing to do with the custom socket, but was caused the results returned by a custom node I've written. Thanks for your time. Mike